# Prevent automatic Timestamp change in SQL Server statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

If table has a Timestamp column it's changed every time an UPDATE statement is executed.

We have the following scenario: the Timestamp is used for optimistic concurrency (detection of change) in Linq 2 SQL. This works fine.

But sometimes we want to update a record outside of Linq 2 SQL, executing direct SQL code. We do this and then `ChangeConflictException` occurs during subsequent modifications through Linq 2 SQL, because the Timestamp is changed by that direct statement.

So the questions is as follows: is there any workaround to keep the optimistic concurrency in Linq 2 SQL, but also allow direct modification without raising `ChangeConflictException`?

Comment: Why would you like this behaviour?

Comment: We have to update the DB directly also because Linq 2 SQL doesn't support some of useful SQL functions (in our case Left and Right).

Comment: Are you executing them through Linq 2 Sql's ExecuteQuery?

Comment: Surely what you should want to do here is to load the updated data (including the timestamp) after this not-through-Linq-2-SQL change has been applied, so that you're then working with the correct data?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, what if the query changes multiple rows at once? Reloading each of them back to the DataContext would not be feasible.

Comment: But still, the underlying data has *changed* and you shouldn't just blindly accept the current (stale) values from the Linq2SQL objects, should you? I'd think blindly overwriting whatever changes you'd achieved would be a worse result.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever, it is perfectly acceptable when the direct SQL statement just adds text to one of the fields, so there's no chance of breaking anything by ignoring its change.